# Как реализовать графический редактор на Python с помощью PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlabel, qpainter

Необходимо реализовать графический редактор для начала с базовыми функциями: чтобы можно было открывать изображения, рисовать линии, перетаскивать с помощью мыши фигуры из меню на изображение (это самое важное). 
Я использую Python и PyQt5.

Может кто-то подскажет ресурсы, с помощью которых это можно реализовать?
Или похожие проекты или видео на YouTube, где реализуются такие функции графического редактора?
Или может кто-то знает виджеты хотя бы, с помощью которых можно реализовать перетаскивание фигуры на полотно?
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Да есть такой графический редактор

**main.py**

````
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


# window class
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # setting title
        self.setWindowTitle("Paint with PyQt5")

        # setting geometry to main window
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        # creating image object
        self.image = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_RGB32)

        # making image color to white
        self.image.fill(Qt.white)

        # variables
        # drawing flag
        self.drawing = False
        # default brush size
        self.brushSize = 2
        # default color
        self.brushColor = Qt.black

        # QPoint object to tract the point
        self.lastPoint = QPoint()

        # creating menu bar
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()

        # creating file menu for save and clear action
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu("File")

        # adding brush size to main menu
        b_size = mainMenu.addMenu("Brush Size")

        # adding brush color to ain menu
        b_color = mainMenu.addMenu("Brush Color")

        # creating save action
        saveAction = QAction("Save", self)
        # adding short cut for save action
        saveAction.setShortcut("Ctrl + S")
        # adding save to the file menu
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAction)
        # adding action to the save
        saveAction.triggered.connect(self.save)

        # creating clear action
        clearAction = QAction("Clear", self)
        # adding short cut to the clear action
        clearAction.setShortcut("Ctrl + C")
        # adding clear to the file menu
        fileMenu.addAction(clearAction)
        # adding action to the clear
        clearAction.triggered.connect(self.clear)

        # creating options for brush sizes
        # creating action for selecting pixel of 4px
        pix_4 = QAction("4px", self)
        # adding this action to the brush size
        b_size.addAction(pix_4)
        # adding method to this
        pix_4.triggered.connect(self.Pixel_4)

        # similarly repeating above steps for different sizes
        pix_7 = QAction("7px", self)
        b_size.addAction(pix_7)
        pix_7.triggered.connect(self.Pixel_7)

        pix_9 = QAction("9px", self)
        b_size.addAction(pix_9)
        pix_9.triggered.connect(self.Pixel_9)

        pix_12 = QAction("12px", self)
        b_size.addAction(pix_12)
        pix_12.triggered.connect(self.Pixel_12)

        # creating options for brush color
        # creating action for black color
        black = QAction("Black", self)
        # adding this action to the brush colors
        b_color.addAction(black)
        # adding methods to the black
        black.triggered.connect(self.blackColor)

        # similarly repeating above steps for different color
        white = QAction("White", self)
        b_color.addAction(white)
        white.triggered.connect(self.whiteColor)

        green = QAction("Green", self)
        b_color.addAction(green)
        green.triggered.connect(self.greenColor)

        yellow = QAction("Yellow", self)
        b_color.addAction(yellow)
        yellow.triggered.connect(self.yellowColor)

        red = QAction("Red", self)
        b_color.addAction(red)
        red.triggered.connect(self.redColor)

    # method for checking mouse cicks
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        # if left mouse button is pressed
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # make drawing flag true
            self.drawing = True
            # make last point to the point of cursor
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()

    # method for tracking mouse activity
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

        # checking if left button is pressed and drawing flag is true
        if (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton) & self.drawing:
            # creating painter object
            painter = QPainter(self.image)

            # set the pen of the painter
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize,
                                Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))

            # draw line from the last point of cursor to the current point
            # this will draw only one step
            painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())

            # change the last point
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()
            # update
            self.update()

    # method for mouse left button release
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):

        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # make drawing flag false
            self.drawing = False

    # paint event
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # create a canvas
        canvasPainter = QPainter(self)

        # draw rectangle  on the canvas
        canvasPainter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image, self.image.rect())

    # method for saving canvas
    def save(self):
        filePath, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save Image", "",
                                                  "PNG(*.png);;JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg);;All Files(*.*) ")

        if filePath == "":
            return
        self.image.save(filePath)

    # method for clearing every thing on canvas
    def clear(self):
        # make the whole canvas white
        self.image.fill(Qt.white)
        # update
        self.update()

    # methods for changing pixel sizes
    def Pixel_4(self):
        self.brushSize = 4

    def Pixel_7(self):
        self.brushSize = 7

    def Pixel_9(self):
        self.brushSize = 9

    def Pixel_12(self):
        self.brushSize = 12

    # methods for changing brush color
    def blackColor(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.black

    def whiteColor(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.white

    def greenColor(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.green

    def yellowColor(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.yellow

    def redColor(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.red


# create pyqt5 app
App = QApplication(sys.argv)

# create the instance of our Window
window = Window()

# showing the window
window.show()

# start the app
sys.exit(App.exec())```
````

Сразу говорю это только **Базовый редактор** который вы и просили.
Ресурс который я вам советую это: [Обучение как это сделать](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pyqt5-create-paint-application/)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо **Martin Fitzpatrick** за [**его труды**](https://www.pythonguis.com/books/). 
Один из вариантов [графического редактора](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/bitmap-graphics/) в его исполнение,
выглядит так:

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

QPushButton.pressed_right = pyqtSignal()


from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

import os
import random
import types


SPRAY_PAINT_SD = 10
SPRAY_PAINT_N = 100

COLORS = [
    '#000000', '#82817f', '#820300', '#868417', '#007e03', '#037e7b', '#040079',
    '#81067a', '#7f7e45', '#05403c', '#0a7cf6', '#093c7e', '#7e07f9', '#7c4002',

    '#ffffff', '#c1c1c1', '#f70406', '#fffd00', '#08fb01', '#0bf8ee', '#0000fa',
    '#b92fc2', '#fffc91', '#00fd83', '#87f9f9', '#8481c4', '#dc137d', '#fb803c',
]

MODES = [
    'selectpoly', 'selectrect',
    'eraser', 'fill',
    'dropper', 'stamp',
    'pen', 'brush',
    'spray', 'text',
    'line', 'polyline',
    'rect', 'polygon',
    'ellipse', 'roundrect'
]

CANVAS_DIMENSIONS = 600, 400

STAMP_DIR = './stamps'
STAMPS = [os.path.join(STAMP_DIR, f) for f in os.listdir(STAMP_DIR)]

SELECTION_PEN = QPen(QColor(0xff, 0xff, 0xff), 1, Qt.DashLine)
PREVIEW_PEN = QPen(QColor(0xff, 0xff, 0xff), 1, Qt.SolidLine)

class Canvas(QLabel):

    mode = 'rectangle'

    primary_color = QColor(Qt.black)
    secondary_color = None

    primary_color_updated = pyqtSignal(str)
    secondary_color_updated = pyqtSignal(str)

    active_color = None
    preview_pen = None

    timer_event = None

    current_stamp = None

    def initialize(self):
        self.background_color = QColor(self.secondary_color) if self.secondary_color else QColor(Qt.white)
        self.eraser_color = QColor(self.secondary_color) if self.secondary_color else QColor(Qt.white)
        self.eraser_color.setAlpha(100)
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        # Create the pixmap for display.
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap(*CANVAS_DIMENSIONS))

        # Clear the canvas.
        self.pixmap().fill(self.background_color)

    def set_primary_color(self, hex):
        self.primary_color = QColor(hex)

    def set_secondary_color(self, hex):
        self.secondary_color = QColor(hex)

    def set_mode(self, mode):
        # Clean up active timer animations.
        self.timer_cleanup()
        # Reset mode-specific vars (all)
        self.active_shape_fn = None
        self.active_shape_args = ()

        self.origin_pos = None

        self.current_pos = None
        self.last_pos = None

        self.history_pos = None
        self.last_history = []

        self.current_text = ""
        self.last_text = ""

        self.dash_offset = 0
        self.locked = False
        # Apply the mode
        self.mode = mode

    def reset_mode(self):
        self.set_mode(self.mode)

    def on_timer(self):
        if self.timer_event:
            self.timer_event()

    def timer_cleanup(self):
        if self.timer_event:
            # Stop the timer, then trigger cleanup.
            timer_event = self.timer_event
            self.timer_event = None
            timer_event(final=True)

    # Mouse events.

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        fn = getattr(self, "%s_mousePressEvent" % self.mode, None)
        if fn:
            return fn(e)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        fn = getattr(self, "%s_mouseMoveEvent" % self.mode, None)
        if fn:
            return fn(e)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        fn = getattr(self, "%s_mouseReleaseEvent" % self.mode, None)
        if fn:
            return fn(e)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, e):
        fn = getattr(self, "%s_mouseDoubleClickEvent" % self.mode, None)
        if fn:
            return fn(e)

    # Generic events (shared by brush-like tools)

    def generic_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.last_pos = e.pos()

        if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.active_color = self.primary_color
        else:
            self.active_color = self.secondary_color

    def generic_mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.last_pos = None

    # Mode-specific events.

    # Select polygon events

    def selectpoly_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        if not self.locked or e.button == Qt.RightButton:
            self.active_shape_fn = 'drawPolygon'
            self.preview_pen = SELECTION_PEN
            self.generic_poly_mousePressEvent(e)

    def selectpoly_timerEvent(self, final=False):
        self.generic_poly_timerEvent(final)

    def selectpoly_mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if not self.locked:
            self.generic_poly_mouseMoveEvent(e)

    def selectpoly_mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, e):
        self.current_pos = e.pos()
        self.locked = True

    def selectpoly_copy(self):
        """
        Copy a polygon region from the current image, returning it.

        Create a mask for the selected area, and use it to blank
        out non-selected regions. Then get the bounding rect of the
        selection and crop to produce the smallest possible image.

        :return: QPixmap of the copied region.
        """
        self.timer_cleanup()

        pixmap = self.pixmap().copy()
        bitmap = QBitmap(*CANVAS_DIMENSIONS)
        bitmap.clear()  # Starts with random data visible.

        p = QPainter(bitmap)
        # Construct a mask where the user selected area will be kept, the rest removed from the image is transparent.
        userpoly = QPolygon(self.history_pos + [self.current_pos])
        p.setPen(QPen(Qt.color1))
        p.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.color1))  # Solid color, Qt.color1 == bit on.
        p.drawPolygon(userpoly)
        p.end()

        # Set our created mask on the image.
        pixmap.setMask(bitmap)

        # Calculate the bounding rect and return a copy of that region.
        return pixmap.copy(userpoly.boundingRect())

    # Select rectangle events

    def selectrect_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.active_shape_fn = 'drawRect'
        self.preview_pen = SELECTION_PEN
        self.generic_shape_mousePressEvent(e)

    def selectrect_timerEvent(self, final=False):
        self.generic_shape_timerEvent(final)

    def selectrect_mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if not self.locked:
            self.current_pos = e.pos()

    def selectrect_mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.current_pos = e.pos()
        self.locked = True

    def selectrect_copy(self):
        """
        Copy a rectangle region of the current image, returning it.

        :return: QPixmap of the copied region.
        """
        self.timer_cleanup()
        return self.pixmap().copy(QRect(self.origin_pos, self.current_pos))

    # Eraser events

    def eraser_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_mousePressEvent(e)

    def eraser_mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.last_pos:
            p = QPainter(self.pixmap())
            p.setPen(QPen(self.eraser_color, 30, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
            p.drawLine(self.last_pos, e.pos())

            self.last_pos = e.pos()
            self.update()

    def eraser_mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_mouseReleaseEvent(e)

    # Stamp (pie) events

    def stamp_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        p = QPainter(self.pixmap())
        stamp = self.current_stamp
        p.drawPixmap(e.x() - stamp.width() // 2, e.y() - stamp.height() // 2, stamp)
        self.update()

    # Pen events

    def pen_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_mousePressEvent(e)

    def pen_mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.last_pos:
            p = QPainter(self.pixmap())
            p.setPen(QPen(self.active_color, 1, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
            p.drawLine(self.last_pos, e.pos())

            self.last_pos = e.pos()
            self.update()

    def pen_mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_mouseReleaseEvent(e)

    # Brush events

    def brush_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_mousePressEvent(e)

    def brush_mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.last_pos:
            p = QPainter(self.pixmap())
            p.setPen(QPen(self.active_color, 10, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
            p.drawLine(self.last_pos, e.pos())

            self.last_pos = e.pos()
            self.update()

    def brush_mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_mouseReleaseEvent(e)

    # Spray events

    def spray_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_mousePressEvent(e)

    def spray_mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.last_pos:
            p = QPainter(self.pixmap())
            p.setPen(QPen(self.active_color, 1))

            for n in range(SPRAY_PAINT_N):
                xo, yo = random.gauss(0, SPRAY_PAINT_SD), random.gauss(0, SPRAY_PAINT_SD)
                p.drawPoint(e.x() + xo, e.y() + yo)

        self.update()

    def spray_mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_mouseReleaseEvent(e)

    # Text events

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if self.mode == 'text':
            if e.key() == Qt.Key_Backspace:
                self.current_text = self.current_text[:-1]
            else:
                self.current_text = self.current_text + e.text()

    def text_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.current_pos = e.pos()
            self.current_text = ""
            self.timer_event = self.text_timerEvent

        elif e.button() == Qt.RightButton and self.current_pos:
            self.timer_cleanup()
            # Draw the text to the image
            p = QPainter(self.pixmap())
            p.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            p.setFont(QFont("Times", 30))
            pen = QPen(self.primary_color, 1, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin)
            p.setPen(pen)
            p.drawText(self.current_pos, self.current_text)
            self.update()

            self.reset_mode()

    def text_timerEvent(self, final=False):
        p = QPainter(self.pixmap())
        p.setFont(QFont("Times", 30))
        p.setCompositionMode(QPainter.RasterOp_SourceXorDestination)
        pen = PREVIEW_PEN
        p.setPen(pen)
        if self.last_text:
            p.drawText(self.current_pos, self.last_text)

        if not final:
            p.drawText(self.current_pos, self.current_text)

        self.last_text = self.current_text
        self.update()

    # Fill events

    def fill_mousePressEvent(self, e):

        if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.active_color = self.primary_color
        else:
            self.active_color = self.secondary_color

        # Convert to image for pixel-by-pixel reading.
        image = self.pixmap().toImage()
        w, h = image.width(), image.height()
        s = image.bits().asstring(w * h * 4)

        x, y = e.x(), e.y()
        # Lookup the 3-byte value at our current location.
        i = (x + (y * w)) * 4
        target_color = s[i:i+3]

        # Convert bytestring to 1byte pp. true/false for matching colour. True values
        # will be 255, non-matching 0. Simplifies the lookup in get_pixel and
        # comparison in the main loop giving slight performance increase.
        s = b''.join(b'\xff' if s[n:n+3] == target_color else b'\x00' for n in range(0, len(s), 4))

        def get_pixel(x, y):
            i = (x + (y * w))
            return s[i]

        have_seen = set()
        to_fill = []
        queue = [(x, y)]

        def get_cardinal_points(have_seen, center_pos):
            points = []
            cx, cy = center_pos
            for x, y in [(1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)]:
                xx, yy = cx + x, cy + y
                if (xx >= 0 and xx < w and
                    yy >= 0 and yy < h and
                    (xx, yy) not in have_seen):

                    points.append((xx, yy))
                    have_seen.add((xx, yy))

            return points

        while queue:
            x, y = queue.pop()
            if get_pixel(x, y):  # 255 for a match (True) or 0 for a miss (False)
                to_fill.append((x,y))
                queue.extend(get_cardinal_points(have_seen, (x, y)))

        if to_fill:
            # Now we have the points, perform the fill.
            p = QPainter(self.pixmap())
            p.setPen(QPen(self.active_color))
            p.drawPoints(*[QPoint(*xy) for xy in to_fill])
            self.update()

    # Dropper events

    def dropper_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        c = self.pixmap().toImage().pixel(e.pos())
        hex = QColor(c).name()

        if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.set_primary_color(hex)
            self.primary_color_updated.emit(hex)  # Update UI.

        elif e.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.set_secondary_color(hex)
            self.secondary_color_updated.emit(hex)  # Update UI.

    # Generic shape events: Rectangle, Ellipse, Rounded-rect

    def generic_shape_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.origin_pos = e.pos()
        self.current_pos = e.pos()
        self.timer_event = self.generic_shape_timerEvent

    def generic_shape_timerEvent(self, final=False):
        p = QPainter(self.pixmap())
        p.setCompositionMode(QPainter.RasterOp_SourceXorDestination)
        pen = self.preview_pen
        pen.setDashOffset(self.dash_offset)
        p.setPen(pen)
        if self.last_pos:
            getattr(p, self.active_shape_fn)(QRect(self.origin_pos, self.last_pos), *self.active_shape_args)

        if not final:
            self.dash_offset -= 1
            pen.setDashOffset(self.dash_offset)
            p.setPen(pen)
            getattr(p, self.active_shape_fn)(QRect(self.origin_pos, self.current_pos), *self.active_shape_args)

        self.update()
        self.last_pos = self.current_pos

    def generic_shape_mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        self.current_pos = e.pos()

    def generic_shape_mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        if self.last_pos:
            # Clear up indicator.
            self.timer_cleanup()

            p = QPainter(self.pixmap())
            p.setPen(QPen(self.primary_color, 5, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.SquareCap, Qt.MiterJoin))

            if self.secondary_color:
                p.setBrush(QBrush(self.secondary_color))
            getattr(p, self.active_shape_fn)(QRect(self.origin_pos, e.pos()), *self.active_shape_args)
            self.update()

        self.reset_mode()

    # Line events

    def line_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.origin_pos = e.pos()
        self.current_pos = e.pos()
        self.preview_pen = PREVIEW_PEN
        self.timer_event = self.line_timerEvent

    def line_timerEvent(self, final=False):
        p = QPainter(self.pixmap())
        p.setCompositionMode(QPainter.RasterOp_SourceXorDestination)
        pen = self.preview_pen
        p.setPen(pen)
        if self.last_pos:
            p.drawLine(self.origin_pos, self.last_pos)

        if not final:
            p.drawLine(self.origin_pos, self.current_pos)

        self.update()
        self.last_pos = self.current_pos

    def line_mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        self.current_pos = e.pos()

    def line_mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        if self.last_pos:
            # Clear up indicator.
            self.timer_cleanup()

            p = QPainter(self.pixmap())
            p.setPen(QPen(self.primary_color, 5, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))

            p.drawLine(self.origin_pos, e.pos())
            self.update()

        self.reset_mode()

    # Generic poly events
    def generic_poly_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            if self.history_pos:
                self.history_pos.append(e.pos())
            else:
                self.history_pos = [e.pos()]
                self.current_pos = e.pos()
                self.timer_event = self.generic_poly_timerEvent

        elif e.button() == Qt.RightButton and self.history_pos:
            # Clean up, we're not drawing
            self.timer_cleanup()
            self.reset_mode()

    def generic_poly_timerEvent(self, final=False):
        p = QPainter(self.pixmap())
        p.setCompositionMode(QPainter.RasterOp_SourceXorDestination)
        pen = self.preview_pen
        pen.setDashOffset(self.dash_offset)
        p.setPen(pen)
        if self.last_history:
            getattr(p, self.active_shape_fn)(*self.last_history)

        if not final:
            self.dash_offset -= 1
            pen.setDashOffset(self.dash_offset)
            p.setPen(pen)
            getattr(p, self.active_shape_fn)(*self.history_pos + [self.current_pos])

        self.update()
        self.last_pos = self.current_pos
        self.last_history = self.history_pos + [self.current_pos]

    def generic_poly_mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        self.current_pos = e.pos()

    def generic_poly_mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, e):
        self.timer_cleanup()
        p = QPainter(self.pixmap())
        p.setPen(QPen(self.primary_color, 5, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))

        # Note the brush is ignored for polylines.
        if self.secondary_color:
            p.setBrush(QBrush(self.secondary_color))

        getattr(p, self.active_shape_fn)(*self.history_pos + [e.pos()])
        self.update()
        self.reset_mode()

    # Polyline events

    def polyline_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.active_shape_fn = 'drawPolyline'
        self.preview_pen = PREVIEW_PEN
        self.generic_poly_mousePressEvent(e)

    def polyline_timerEvent(self, final=False):
        self.generic_poly_timerEvent(final)

    def polyline_mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_poly_mouseMoveEvent(e)

    def polyline_mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_poly_mouseDoubleClickEvent(e)

    # Rectangle events

    def rect_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.active_shape_fn = 'drawRect'
        self.active_shape_args = ()
        self.preview_pen = PREVIEW_PEN
        self.generic_shape_mousePressEvent(e)

    def rect_timerEvent(self, final=False):
        self.generic_shape_timerEvent(final)

    def rect_mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_shape_mouseMoveEvent(e)

    def rect_mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_shape_mouseReleaseEvent(e)

    # Polygon events

    def polygon_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.active_shape_fn = 'drawPolygon'
        self.preview_pen = PREVIEW_PEN
        self.generic_poly_mousePressEvent(e)

    def polygon_timerEvent(self, final=False):
        self.generic_poly_timerEvent(final)

    def polygon_mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_poly_mouseMoveEvent(e)

    def polygon_mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_poly_mouseDoubleClickEvent(e)

    # Ellipse events

    def ellipse_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.active_shape_fn = 'drawEllipse'
        self.active_shape_args = ()
        self.preview_pen = PREVIEW_PEN
        self.generic_shape_mousePressEvent(e)

    def ellipse_timerEvent(self, final=False):
        self.generic_shape_timerEvent(final)

    def ellipse_mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_shape_mouseMoveEvent(e)

    def ellipse_mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_shape_mouseReleaseEvent(e)

    # Roundedrect events

    def roundrect_mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.active_shape_fn = 'drawRoundedRect'
        self.active_shape_args = (25, 25)
        self.preview_pen = PREVIEW_PEN
        self.generic_shape_mousePressEvent(e)

    def roundrect_timerEvent(self, final=False):
        self.generic_shape_timerEvent(final)

    def roundrect_mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_shape_mouseMoveEvent(e)

    def roundrect_mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.generic_shape_mouseReleaseEvent(e)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # Replace canvas placeholder from QtDesigner.
        self.horizontalLayout.removeWidget(self.canvas)
        self.canvas = Canvas()
        self.canvas.initialize()
        # We need to enable mouse tracking to follow the mouse without the button pressed.
        self.canvas.setMouseTracking(True)
        # Enable focus to capture key inputs.
        self.canvas.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        # Setup the mode buttons
        mode_group = QButtonGroup(self)
        mode_group.setExclusive(True)

        for mode in MODES:
            btn = getattr(self, '%sButton' % mode)
            btn.pressed.connect(lambda mode=mode: self.canvas.set_mode(mode))
            mode_group.addButton(btn)

        # Setup the color selection buttons.
        self.primaryButton.pressed.connect(lambda: self.choose_color(self.set_primary_color))
        self.secondaryButton.pressed.connect(lambda: self.choose_color(self.set_secondary_color))

        # Initialize button colours.
        for n, hex in enumerate(COLORS, 1):
            btn = getattr(self, 'colorButton_%d' % n)
            btn.setStyleSheet('QPushButton { background-color: %s; }' % hex)
            btn.hex = hex  # For use in the event below

            def patch_mousePressEvent(self_, e):
                if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
                    self.set_primary_color(self_.hex)

                elif e.button() == Qt.RightButton:
                    self.set_secondary_color(self_.hex)

            btn.mousePressEvent = types.MethodType(patch_mousePressEvent, btn)

        # Setup up action signals
        self.actionCopy.triggered.connect(self.copy_to_clipboard)

        # Initialize animation timer.
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.canvas.on_timer)
        self.timer.setInterval(100)
        self.timer.start()

        # Setup to agree with Canvas.
        self.set_primary_color('#000000')
        self.set_secondary_color('#ffffff')

        # Signals for canvas-initiated color changes (dropper).
        self.canvas.primary_color_updated.connect(self.set_primary_color)
        self.canvas.secondary_color_updated.connect(self.set_secondary_color)

        # Setup the stamp state.
        self.current_stamp_n = -1
        self.next_stamp()
        self.stampnextButton.pressed.connect(self.next_stamp)

        # Menu options
        self.actionNewImage.triggered.connect(self.canvas.initialize)
        self.actionOpenImage.triggered.connect(self.open_file)
        self.actionSaveImage.triggered.connect(self.save_file)
        self.actionClearImage.triggered.connect(self.canvas.reset)
        self.actionInvertColors.triggered.connect(self.invert)
        self.actionFlipHorizontal.triggered.connect(self.flip_horizontal)
        self.actionFlipVertical.triggered.connect(self.flip_vertical)

        self.show()

    def choose_color(self, callback):
        dlg = QColorDialog()
        if dlg.exec():
            callback( dlg.selectedColor().name() )

    def set_primary_color(self, hex):
        self.canvas.set_primary_color(hex)
        self.primaryButton.setStyleSheet('QPushButton { background-color: %s; }' % hex)

    def set_secondary_color(self, hex):
        self.canvas.set_secondary_color(hex)
        self.secondaryButton.setStyleSheet('QPushButton { background-color: %s; }' % hex)

    def next_stamp(self):
        self.current_stamp_n += 1
        if self.current_stamp_n >= len(STAMPS):
            self.current_stamp_n = 0

        pixmap = QPixmap(STAMPS[self.current_stamp_n])
        self.stampnextButton.setIcon(QIcon(pixmap))

        self.canvas.current_stamp = pixmap

    def copy_to_clipboard(self):
        clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()

        if self.canvas.mode == 'selectrect' and self.canvas.locked:
            clipboard.setPixmap(self.canvas.selectrect_copy())

        elif self.canvas.mode == 'selectpoly' and self.canvas.locked:
            clipboard.setPixmap(self.canvas.selectpoly_copy())

        else:
            clipboard.setPixmap(self.canvas.pixmap())

    def open_file(self):
        """
        Open image file for editing, scaling the smaller dimension and cropping the remainder.
        :return:
        """
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "", "PNG image files (*.png); JPEG image files (*jpg); All files (*.*)")

        if path:
            pixmap = QPixmap()
            pixmap.load(path)

            # We need to crop down to the size of our canvas. Get the size of the loaded image.
            iw = pixmap.width()
            ih = pixmap.height()

            # Get the size of the space we're filling.
            cw, ch = CANVAS_DIMENSIONS

            if iw/cw < ih/ch:  # The height is relatively bigger than the width.
                pixmap = pixmap.scaledToWidth(cw)
                hoff = (pixmap.height() - ch) // 2
                pixmap = pixmap.copy(
                    QRect(QPoint(0, hoff), QPoint(cw, pixmap.height()-hoff))
                )

            elif iw/cw > ih/ch:  # The height is relatively bigger than the width.
                pixmap = pixmap.scaledToHeight(ch)
                woff = (pixmap.width() - cw) // 2
                pixmap = pixmap.copy(
                    QRect(QPoint(woff, 0), QPoint(pixmap.width()-woff, ch))
                )

            self.canvas.setPixmap(pixmap)


    def save_file(self):
        """
        Save active canvas to image file.
        :return:
        """
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save file", "", "PNG Image file (*.png)")

        if path:
            pixmap = self.canvas.pixmap()
            pixmap.save(path, "PNG" )

    def invert(self):
        img = QImage(self.canvas.pixmap())
        img.invertPixels()
        pixmap = QPixmap()
        pixmap.convertFromImage(img)
        self.canvas.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def flip_horizontal(self):
        pixmap = self.canvas.pixmap()
        self.canvas.setPixmap(pixmap.transformed(QTransform().scale(-1, 1)))

    def flip_vertical(self):
        pixmap = self.canvas.pixmap()
        self.canvas.setPixmap(pixmap.transformed(QTransform().scale(1, -1)))



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модуль [****MainWindow.py** и изображения возьмете здесь**](https://github.com/pythonguis/15-minute-apps/tree/master/paint).

Comment: @АлександрТрифонов что не так?